# Multithreading Python with Docker on Arm/V7

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I stumble on an issue while using the threading lib of Python with Docker on Arm/V7.

The error is the following:

```
Fatal Python error: take_gil: PyCOND_WAIT(gil->cond) failed
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0xb6840d84 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>

Thread 0xb6f8245c (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 320 in wait
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 607 in wait
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 940 in start
  File "//main.py", line 4 in <module>
```

When I run the file `main.py` directly on the raspberry everything goes well; I have an immediate return.

But, when running it through Docker, I obtain the error.
I tried with the alpine and the bullseye version of python3.10 image.

My config is a raspberry pi

```
➜  ~ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103-v7l+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:24:00 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
➜  ~
```

The DockerFile

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "main.py"]

COPY . .

CMD []
```

The `main.py`

```
from threading import Thread

thread = Thread()
thread.start()
```

Thank you for all the help you could provide me.